# Retrofit not returning the correct results from API

Tags: android, api, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit's library in my android app to retrieve records from my "Sync" table in my database on my server (used Loopback to generate the endpoints). I created a custom endpoint that requires a variable of type long which is a timestamp in unix format such as 1466598649119. The problem is that when I call the endpoint

```
@GET("Syncs")
    Call<List<Sync>> getAllSyncsAfterThisTimeStamp(@Query(("getRecodsAfterTimestamp?timeChanged=")) long timeChanged);

   public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

with this value:

```
Long timeStamp = 1466598625506L;
Log.e(TAG, "Job Service task is running...");
getAllSyncsCall = espcService.getAllSyncsAfterThisTimeStamp(timeStamp);
getAllSyncsCall.enqueue(EspcJobSheculerService.this);
```

it should return only the records with timestamp after or equal to the provided one but instead I am retrieving all of the records (the total number of records in my table is 3)

[image]

I know that my end point works because I am testing it on the Loopback's API explorer and it returns the  correct number of records so obviously I am doing something wrong on the device site.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getRecodsAfterTimestamp?timeChanged="` is the problem. `getRecodsAfterTimestamp` is not part of the query but of your path. Retrofit takes car of adding `=` and `?`

```
@GET("Syncs/getRecodsAfterTimestamp")
Call<List<Sync>> getAllSyncsAfterThisTimeStamp(@Query(("timeChanged")) long timeChanged);
```

should do it

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much!